# DateTime class how to deal with negative date interval

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I have a simple function that returns the number of days between two dates using the DateTime diff function. But right now it still returns a positive number if the end date is before the start date. Is there a way to return a negative difference using this method? Or would I bet better just to check with strtotime first in my function? Ideally I think I will just return 0 of its a negative difference.

```
//Returns the total number of days between two dates
function count_days($start_date, $end_date){

    $d1 = new DateTime($start_date);
    $d2 = new DateTime($end_date);
    $difference = $d1->diff($d2);
    return $difference->days;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`r` flag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) to get the negative sign in there:

```
function count_days($start_date, $end_date){

    $d1 = new DateTime($start_date);
    $d2 = new DateTime($end_date);
    $difference = $d1->diff($d2);
    return $difference->format('%r%a days');

}
```

Comment: Ahh thanks and what about checking if it is a negative?

Comment: You could check if `$d2 < $d1` before doing this to see if it is negative.

Comment: Ahh I see as simple as that eh

Comment: The answer *usually* is. :)

Comment: what are the other '%'s like %a and %r that we can use :)

Answer (score 2):

Check for $difference->invert

```
function count_days($start_date, $end_date){

   $d1 = new DateTime($start_date);
   $d2 = new DateTime($end_date);
   $difference = $d1->diff($d2);
   if ($difference->invert == 1) { //if 1 then difference will in minus other wise inplus
      return -$difference->d;
   } else {
     return $difference->d;
   }
```

}